# Displaying qTip hover on outer nodes of Cytoscape.js graph?

Tags: qtip2, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

When hovering over the outer nodes of graph in Cytoscape.js, the qTip dialog is not displayed.

Is there anyway to display the qTip bubbles upon hovering on an outer node? I can have the qtip popup on nodes in the upper half but not much along the sides of the graph. Especially towards the bottom half.

```
            cy.elements('node').qtip({

            id: function() {
                return this.data('id');
            },
            content: function() {
                return this.data('name') + '<br /><em>$' + this.data('weight') + '</em>';
            },
            position: {
                my: 'bottom right',
                viewport: $(etl_cyto_div),
                adjust: {
                    cyViewport: true,
                    method: 'flip none'
                }
            },
            show: {
                cyBgOnly: false
            },
            hide: {
                cyBgOnly: false,
                cyViewport: true,
                delay: 100
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-tipsy',
                tip: {
                    width: 16,
                    height: 8
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have found that this is an issue with cytoscape not re-acting to hovers. I took qTip off and set up a function to log the node ID on hover. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your options may be causing the issue.  Because this extension is a relatively thin wrapper around qtip, you just use the [qTip API and options](http://qtip2.com/options).

- Try leaving `options.position.adjust.method` default
- Try a more permissive `options.position.adjust.method`; see [qtip docs](http://qtip2.com/options#position.adjustmethod)
- `adjust.cyViewport` is expensive (especially on touch) and can be buggy depending on the version of qtip used.
- Try all defaults and see if you can reproduce your issue with the events you want.  If not, then the issue is due to the set options.  If so, please file your example code [in an issue](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/issues/new)

Comment: I got it to work. I really do not know how. I fiddled around a lot. It may have been another function I was calling that was messing it up. Thank you Max Franz for your help and for creating cytoscape.js. It's a work of art!